# Titration of acid with base or base with acid: can I always use the same indicator?

Tags: acid-base, titration

If you are doing a titration with $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{HCl}$, does it matter which one goes in the burette, and will this change the outcome of whether the solution in the beaker will turn pink due to phenolphthalein?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question about titration theory](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53548/question-about-titration-theory)

Answer (score 2):

When phenolphthalein is used as an indicator, NaOH is taken in a burette because then the colour change is from colourless to pink. And this time, it will be easier to observe.

On the other hand, if HCl is taken in a burette, colour change will be from pink to colourless which can't be observed in a single drop.

When NaOH is titrated with HCl using methyl orange as an indicator, HCl is taken in a burette because then the colour at the end point changes from yellow to red which is easier to observe rather than that from red to yellow.

Comment: This is just for the sake of convenience of calculation..